# PhaserJS Canvas Override Bootstrap Modal

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5, phaser-framework, phaserjs

I have a simple game create with phaserJs with Angular and bootstrap for styling. My problem here is when i show bootstrap modal and click inside modal, it's effect to my phaserJS canvas button.

Example preview code: https://github-u3st63.stackblitz.io

Example code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-u3st63

How to fix this? I tried to set z-index to canvas, but it's not working.

Comment: Can you share some code? Do you have an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), because I tried Phaser with bootstrap and it works, as it should. May be the issue is with Angular, that it is passing the click events, but without code it is hard to say.

Comment: @winner_joiner thank you, i've been add an example code

Comment: I added the Tag **Angular** since this is probally a issue with angular and phaser and how both handle the events. I assume some angular-experts can give you here more insides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this seems to be a Angular issue, with the event execution order. Since I'm no expert on Angular. I would suggest simply pausing the game on opening the Modal dialog, with the function `pause`, something like `game.scene.pause('Game')`  and on closing the dialog you simply resume the game with `game.scene.resume('Game')`. [Link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scenes.SceneManager.html#pause__anchor)

[Here is an official phaser demo](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src/scenes/pause%20and%20resume.js&v=3.60.0) showcasing these to functions.

You would only have to wire up the communication between the components.

> ***Info:** Just keep in mind if you have multiple scene running, that you would have to stop them all, and restart them again. In this case simply hiding the game might be a better option.*

Comment: Thank you for your response, i really appreciate it. I will trying your suggestion